# Woodworking routers

Tags: woodworking

I've just purchased an elu 1/4" router. Will I be able to get an half inch router  adapter to fit? Is the router I've purchased any good and can I make a table for it?

Comment: No model information means answers can only be vague generalities.

Comment: See also: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/27513/is-it-possible-to-install-a-1-2-collet-on-my-palm-router

Answer (score 1):

This would be a great question at the new [Woodworking Beta](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/)

Now as to your question, without a model number and make, it's hard to tell. Some 'trim router' models only accept 1/4" shank bits, but most full-sized routers will take either 1/4" or 1/2" bits, with the appropriate collet.

Answer (score 0):

Normally if it's a 1/4" router as sold, you cannot use anything larger. If it could take a 1/2" collet, it would be sold that way. A 1/2" router will normally come with a 1/4" collet as well, and for some a 3/8" collet can be purchased aftermarket (handy if available, since many standard milling cutters are 3/8" shank.)

Usually a 1/2" is a better choice for table use, but it will depend on what you intend to accomplish with it to some extent.